# SQL Server Profiler missing after installation

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know if there is some type of bug in the installation of SQL Server 2008 R2? It seems if you have Express edition installed, then upgrade to anything (developer, enterprise, etc.)  the SQL Server tools that don't come with Express will never show up because the Express edition is installed on your computer. *Even though you just paid for Enterprise edition

This has happened to me on 3 different computers. I have to copy the `binn` folder from a computer that actually works. Just today I decided to try to uninstall the Express edition before upgrading - instead of letting Microsoft handling the upgrade and it worked. I'm thinking maybe this is a bug...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know this question is old and answered, but I was having the same problem. I wanted to upgrade from Express to Developer and none of these answers helped me.

What I´ve done to be able to add features is:

1. Open the SQL Server Installation Center.
2. Click on Maintenance > Edition Upgrade and follow the steps.
3. Click on Installation > New installation or add features to an existing installation and follow the steps.

There you can add all the new features from your new version of SQL Server. Hope that helped..

Answer (score 31):

When you upgrade from Express version, need to install **Management Tools - Complete** -

[image: Management Tools - Complete]

Comment: Reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143786(v=sql.100).ASPX MSDN article and I was lead to believe it was Client Tools that held the Profiler but it is as you say underneath Management Tools - Complete that it resides.
Annoyingly this is not detailed in the Setup before *after* the 'Management Tools - Basic' package is installed.

Answer (score 10):

*(Instructions for 2008 R2)*

If you installed Express before Enterprise/Developer you most likely have **Management Tools - Basic** installed.  I used the following steps to get SQL Server Profiler Installed, which is bundled with the **Management Tools - Complete** tool set.

**Step 1: Remove Management Tools - Basic**

1. Control "Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features"
2. Uninstall/Change "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2"
3. Select "Remove"
4. In the "Select Instance" dialog, "Instances to remove features from:" drop-down choose **Remove shared features only**
5. Check "Management Tools - Basic"
6. Follow the rest of the uninstall dialogs

**Step 2: Install Management Tools - Complete**

1. Run setup from the Enterprise\Developer Edition installation media
2. Choose "New installation or add features to an existing installation"
3. A few screens later choose "SQL Server Feature Installation"
4. Check "Shared Features -> Management Tools-Complete"
5. Follow the rest of the dialogs to install.

You should now have SQL Server Profiler installed.

Comment: Can I do this while the SQL database is still running? Or do I need to stop / restart the SQL server and/or server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select full management tools in the features during install I believe. Just go run the installer again, select modify existing instance, and add the checkboxes for management tools

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server installation, when doing an upgrade, is only going to upgrade those components currently installed. If you want the additional tools available with a higher edition you will have to rerun the installation and select to add addtional components. Then as Darren suggested select the full management tools option.